# How to Convert a Div content to image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a div and inside it exists one gridview and few other divs. Now I want to convert its contents to an image and store it on the server. I don't want to send it to client.
How can I do it?

Comment: do you want to save its representation in UI or its html content?

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217890/save-rendered-html-as-image

Comment: @Developer I want to save it's representation. The result of html.

Answer (score 0):

The Page Content will be process in browser and browser is in client side
so you dont now how it seems in server side ,in server side we just have html and scripts ... 
so the link ddrace gave may be usefull, or you can develope  a windows App and put a webbrowser on it and load your page in the browser  and save the image of browser  to the server

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use a piece of middleware to do this.  I have used this one in the past: http://www.winnovative-software.com/Html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx .  I know it says "to PDF", but one of it's features is that it can render the result to an image and save it in various image formats.

In your web application, have the middleware components bring the web-page down that has your control etc on it, and save it as an image on the server.